# Local notification, applicationIconBadgeNumber remains when app is in foreground

Tags: objective-c, ios

When app is in foreground, even if I set the applicationBadgeNumber to 0, when I quit the app, there's still a "1" badge on my app, even whem I kill it, any ideas? When I open the notification when the app is in background, no problem at all!

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification 
    {   
        NSLog(@"%i", notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber); // Return 1
        notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        NSLog(@"%i", notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber); // Return 0

        UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];

        if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive)
        {
            // Application was in the background when notification
            // was delivered.
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"An item is asking your attention" message:nil delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Show me", nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where are you setting the applicationBadgeNumber?  I think you are setting the **notification** badge number.

Try this:

```
 application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Comment: That did the trick! What's the difference betweens etting the notification badge vs the application badge? application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0; vs notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

Comment: Frankly, I'm not sure what it means to set the badge number on the notification - that seems like something the OS would do.  All I know for sure is the line of code above is how you set the applications badge count.  Glad it's working!

Comment: The badge number of the notification is the number that the badge of the app icon will be set to when the notification fires. Sadly, it is a static number.
In the case quoted changing this number AFTER the notification has fired will have no effect (except the case when this is a recurring notification).

Answer (score 7):

In my app, clicking on the icon acknowledges any outstanding notifications. So when I close the app, it always resets the application icon badge number. In the app delegate, add a method to reset the badge number in the `applicationWillResignActive` method, like so:

```
- (void) applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [application setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the provided `application` variable?

Comment: Sure, that would also be effective. I typed this up quickly a few years ago. I'll edit to match your comment.